# Calling Known Property from Unknown Class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a BaseClass from which I have derived multiple other Classes using Inheritance.
Elsewhere I want to be able to retrieve Properties from anyone of these inherited classes even though the type of Class isn't known until Runtime.

For example lets say I have two classes derived from BaseClass

```
FirstClass : BaseClass
SecondClass : BaseClass
```

My BaseClass has a property called ID which is an int (amongst many others)

At runtime my app will receive 'either' a FirstClass object or a SecondClass object, but either way I need to retrieve the ID property.

```
public int MyMethod(object unknownClass)
{
    int myID = unknownClass.ID; 
    return myID                    //...does not compile
}

public int MyMethod(object unknownClass)
{
    BaseClass tryCasting = (BaseClass)unknownClass;
    int myID = tryCasting.ID;           
    return myID                    //...does not compile either
}
```

I'm not sure what else to try.
How can I get a Property which I **know** exists without **knowing** the Object type first?

Comment: What is the error with your second method? There is a missing semicolon, but I expect that's not what you're talking about.

Comment: @TimRogers if you look closely he missed the semicolon always at his return's

Comment: @PJW: Have you heard about inheritance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use object and use `BaseClass`:

```
public int MyMethod(BaseClass unknownClass)
{
    int myID = unknownClass.ID; 
    return myID;                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the answer from Darren Davies for your specific case of ID. The approaches in this answer are useful when the property is defined in the derived classes, not the base class.

---

Use `dynamic` instead of `object`. That will use the runtime to retrieve the actual object type.

```
public int MyMethod(dynamic unknownClass)
{
    int myID = (int)unknownClass.ID; 
    return myID;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Reflection to retrieve the property value:

```
var myID = (int)unknownClass.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(unknownClass);
```

Comment: `dynamic` is not a good approach if you can easily avoid it. As well as being slow, it has the potential to turn compilation errors into runtime errors.

Comment: Both `dynamic` and reflection seem like a bit of overkill.

Comment: Same opinion for reflection. It's an abuse of these features.

Comment: In OP's case - this *is* overkill, but this was also my first thought after i saw the title, and the word *unknown* a lot of times. If the class is truely unknown, then this is the best answer.

Comment: You **hardly ever need reflection**, unless you're building a serialization library or stuff like that. There's no such thing as an unknown class, that's called "I don't know what interfaces are".

Answer (score 1):

Polymorfism is the answer. You should know that when you create a class derived from another, the derived class acquires inmediately the properties from the base class. Thus, if you don't redefine the method (override), when you call the method `MyMethod` on a derived class it will
always call the base method. So the next code should work well :

```
BaseClass { 
    private : int id ; 
    public  : int getId { return id ; }
} ;

FirstClass : BaseClass { DO NOT OVERRIDE getID ...} ; 

int main (void) { 
    BaseClass base ; 
    FirstClass first ; 
    base = first ; 
    base.getId() ; //Gets the id of first.
}
```

What does this program?  When you assign `first` to `base` you upcast `first` type to `BaseClass`. Then when you get to the execution of `base.getId()` the program lookups if 
there is a redefinition (overriding) of this method in FirstClass, if there isn't it calls the base method.

Hope that you find this information useful. You should read the first chapters of "Thinking in C++" of Bruce Eckels, it's a good introduction to Object Oriented Programming.